# Creating music with batch

Tags: batch-file

i wanted to know if there is some way of doing music with batch, not just opening a mp3 file from cmd, but commands to do notes or something like that. If there really isn't how to do it, i understand.

Comment: Batch has nothing like this. The closest you can get is the system beep, but you can't change the tone or duration.

Comment: Incorrect, batch is perfectly capable.

Comment: @T3RR0R, I think the user is actually asking how to create their own code to create musical tones through the speakers. Kind of like a midi piano or tone generator.  I don't think they are looking to launch audio files to do this.

Comment: @matheus, I think this may be what you are looking for but it is for Powershell. You can call powershell commands from a batch file if you really need to.  [Music from the Command Line](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20989.music-from-the-command-line-performed-by-powershell.aspx)

Comment: Their question isn't clear enough tbh. `Music, but not just opening an MP3, notes, or something like that.` A somewhat broad statement as opposed to a clear and concise question. The solution I proposed can be used to play a variety of short sound files of different extensions in fairly rapid succession. If they are looking directly to generate sound tones, then no, batch cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

batch can play music by creating and starting a vbs script to Leverage the internal windows media player.

Note: In all the below scripts, the variable %sounds% refers to the folder your sound scripts are located, and must be defined.

The core of playing music is the following Batch Script:

```
@Echo off & REM MusicPlayer.bat

    Set "MusicPath=%~1" & REM Full Path for the music file
    Set "vol=%~2" & REM Volume as number between 0 and 100
    Set "LoopTF=%~3" & REM 'paramater 3 as 'true' or 'false' determines if the track is to be looped.

    (
    PUSHD %sounds%
    %= Change to the directory your sound files are located =%)

::: Ensure no Conflict with the Previous Script.

    IF exist PlayMusic.vbs (
    DEL PlayMusic.vbs
    )

::: Creates a vbs Script to launch the music (Occurs without any visual indication or prompting)

    (
    echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
    echo Sound.URL = "%MusicPath%"
    echo Sound.settings.volume = %vol%
    echo Sound.settings.setMode "loop", %LoopTF%
    echo Sound.Controls.play
    echo While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
    echo      WScript.Sleep 100
    echo Wend
    echo Sound objTS = Nothing 'Destroy the object.
    )>PlayMusic.vbs

    start /min PlayMusic.vbs

    (
    POPD
    %= Return to your Previous Directory =%)
::: Exit the Launcher and return to Previous batch program.

    GOTO :EOF
```

The above script is called with 3 parameters as Remarked.

Another Vbs can be used to Monitor the batch's status and call a batch script to stop the music when the batch is closed:

```
@Echo off & REM Monitor.bat

(
ECHO Set objWMIService = GetObject ("winmgmts:"^)
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^)
ECHO DO while proc.count ^> 0
ECHO Set proc = objWMIService.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Process Where Name='cmd.exe'"^)
ECHO if proc.count ^< 1 then exit do
ECHO wscript.sleep 1500
ECHO loop
ECHO Set WshShell=createobject("wscript.shell"^)
ECHO WshShell.run "%sounds%\KillMusic.bat", 0, true
)>%sounds%\MusicMonitor.vbs

start %sounds%\MusicMonitor.vbs
Goto :EOF
```

The above script creates a hidden vbs that fetches the number of instances of cmd.exe via the objWMIService.ExecQuery. This occurs during a loop, with the break condition being 0 open cmd.exe windows. A sleep is built into the loop to reduce the frequency of calls to the WMI service, as these are very resource intensive. When the loop break occurs, it starts the killmusic.bat program in a hidden state.

The below script "KillMusic.bat" is called either directly in your quit label or by the vbs monitor when it determines Cmd.exe is no longer running. `DoMonitor` is a variable that is changed in your main script prior to killmusic being called. `1` indicates the monitor should be restarted, and is used when killmusic.bat stops a currently playing song to start a new song. `Monitor` is a Variable containing the path to Monitor.bat

```
@ECHO OFF & REM KillMusic.bat

    taskkill /pid WScript.exe /f /t >nul

    IF exist "%sounds%\PlayMusic.vbs" (
        DEL /Q "%sounds%\PlayMusic.vbs"
    )

    Timeout 1 > nul

    IF "%DoMonitor%"=="1" GOTO reset

GOTO :EOF

:reset

    CALL "%Monitor%"

GOTO :EOF
```

[These three programs can be seen in effect here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qK5IG3oX5mI)

Comment: Playing notes / SFX is as simple as having a collection of effect files to play with LoopTF set to False.

Comment: Killmusic only needs to be called when changing songs, and in this circumstance, the DoMontior variable should be switched On (1) before the call, and Off after the call (0)